# JSP export queried result to Excel w/o displaytag

Tags: excel, jsp, export

I wish to export my queried result to excel or csv.
I usually use function in display tag to export to csv, 
but this time...
The problem is that records will be over 20,000 so I do not want to display the result, but just to provide excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a servlet, write the data in CSV (or Excel) format to the response output stream, and make sure to set the appropriate content-type on the response and to set the following header:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=someFile.csv");
```

There are lots of libraries to generate CSV or Excel from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). Another option is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).